# How to iterate a TreeMap until a specific key?

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I want iterate a TreeMap until a specific key .

```
      for (int i = 0 ; i < specifickey  ; i++)
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: get keySet of map and then iterate through it

Comment: But in this way I iterate all the map ! i want to break the cycle when I find that specific key.

Comment: Use headMap as TreeMap implements NavigableMap from java6 onwards.+1

Answer (score 6):

`TreeMap` implements `NavigableMap` which can be useful to iterate over a range of keys.It is internally backed by the `Map`,so any changes you do to the Map is reflected vice-versa.You should use a `headMap(K toKey, boolean inclusive)` to get the map

```
NavigableMap<K,V> navigableMap = map.headMap(toKey, true);

for(Map.Entry entry : navigableMap .entrySet()){

//use the key value pair in Map.Entry
}
```

Comment: +1: At least a decent answer that makes usage of `TreeMap` useful methods.

Answer (score 0):

Like every other map:

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = ...;

for (int key : map.keySet()) {
    if(key == yourValue) {
        //value found
    }
}
```

Edit: Read your question again, if you only want to find out, if a key is present, then:

```
if(map.containsKey(key)) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to iterate over the keys:

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    if (key.equals(target)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

If you also need to access the values, then it's more efficient to iterate over the entries instead of the keys:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
String target = "something";

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().equals(target)) {
        // do something with entry.getValue()
    }
}
```